# R ggplot2, "invalid unit" error when using geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, runtime-error

I get the following error using geom_histogram() in ggplot2. Below it is reproduced with standard example data from R, but this seems to happen with any data I provide. I was unable to find explanations and I was unable to debug up through the origin of the error.
Any guess? I am using RStudio Version 1.4.1106.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat)) + geom_histogram(bins=30) 
Error in unit(unclass(x), attr(x, "unit"), attr(x, "data")) : 
  Invalid unit
```

Comment: May you provide a snippet of your data?

Comment: Can't reproduce on macOs R v4.1.1.

Comment: @mikebader the "diamonds" dataset is included by default in R.

Comment: Oops, sorry! Do you have any other libraries loaded?

Comment: No, just ggplot2.

Comment: Here, it works. Windows, R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) -- "Shake and Throw"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error arised from the fact the version of ggplot2 installed was older than the R version (I have to install the packages from a local repository, so sometimes they are not updated).
Once I installed the lastest version, it disappeared.
Thanks to everyone who investigated the issue.

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer to your own question. It makes it easier for people to search for unanswered questions.